Include missing server in Grafana Alert message
I have some servers sending basic metrics to Influxdb every 10 seconds and I have an alert setup in Grafana to be notified whenever a server stops sending them (ie, went down):
from(bucket: "metrics")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "met.cpu")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "cpu_p")
  |> group()
  |> unique(column: "hostname")
  |> keep(columns: ["hostname"])
  |> count(column: "hostname")

Then condition is set to when last() below <NUMBER_OF_SERVERS>
While this works, I'd like to improve the alert to be able to quickly identify the server in the message.
I'd be ok with setting up individual alerts (filtering by hostname) as long as I could re-use the same query to avoid hitting influx more only because of this.
Or to set individual conditions on the same alert, if I could write one like if <hostname> not in query (and drop the count)
But I've been unable to find any solution so far.
